# retrieving same column twice from a table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table named "address", which has:

- id
- title
- parent_id

...fields.

In the title column, the name of regions and districts are inserted. The regions have parent_id value of zero, and parent_id of the districts are id of the regions.

I want a query which display regions in one column and it's respective districts in another column.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a Region table and a District table?

Comment: Your question is really not clear. Does title store both region and district? How?

Comment: @amarillion - I think GJ means he has one table which stores both Regions and Districts. Regions will always have a parent_id of 0; District's parent_id will be the id of the Region they belong to. The title field will store the name of the Region or District, depending on what "type" the row is.

Answer (score 5):

You could join the table onto itself like this:

```
SELECT
   R.Title AS Region,
   D.Title AS District
FROM
   address R
INNER JOIN
   address D
   ON
   D.parent_id = R.id
   AND
   D.parent_id > 0
WHERE
   R.parent_id = 0
```

However your table structure is a bit odd, I would do some reading on database normalization.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like the following:

```
Select r.Region, s.State 
from
    (Select id, title as Region from address where parent_id=0) as r,
    (Select id, title as State, parent_id from address where parent_id>0) as s
where s.parent_id = r.id
```

Its an ANSI SQL. You can further tune it for your need.

Comment: ANSI-89 to be specific.  ANSI-92, like you see in Graham's answer, is preferrable.